# Which approach to use for customizing django-registration-redux

Tags: python, django

The first thing I did was of course customizing forms, views and templates in site-packages. And then I learned that everything will be reset to default after upgrading the package.
So now I decided to create a new application "accounts" and make customizations there.
My question is which approach is better (haven't tried any, sorry)

First approach:

1. Set INCLUDE_REGISTER_URL = False
2. in accounts.views import RegistrationView and create MyRegistrationView (same thing with forms)
3. in accounts.urls include registration.backends.default.urls and create my own urlpattern for MyRegistrationView
4. create custom templates in templates/registration
5. put registration above django.contrib.admin in INSTALLED_APPS

Second approach:

1. in accounts.views import RegistrationView and create MyRegistrationView (same thing with forms)
2. Create complete replica of registration.backends.default.urls in accounts.urls with my new custom template names
3. put custom templates inside my accounts app

Or are there any better approaches? (probably are)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to override almost every part of redux, wont it be better to use built-in django authentication and to extend it as you wish?

Yes, you are on the right way. You need to override those things you do not like by coping them to your project and then by changing the copy. Though it's will be a cleaner code if you place templates in `templates/registration`, views in `views.py` and etc, actually you can do in some other way you wish.

Comment: Well I "only" want to override templates so I can style them a little, and add a few fields to `RegistrationForm` and then I have to change `form_class` in `RegistrationView` and so on. I like the two step backend and activation links that django-registration-redux provides. Thank you for your answer